# XML::Bare forcearray

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to parse the following XML data with
[`XML::Bare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Bare)

```
<xml>
  <a>
    <b>1</b>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>
      <b>3</b>
    </c>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>4</b>
    <c>
      <b>5</b>
      <b>6</b>
    </c>
    <c>
      <b>7</b>
    </c>
  </a>
</xml>
```

with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Bare qw( forcearray );

my $ob   = new XML::Bare( file => "tst.xml" );
my $root = $ob->parse();

forcearray($root->{xml}->{a});
my @as = @{ $root->{xml}->{a} }

foreach ( @as ) {

    print $ob->xml($_);

    forcearray($_->{b});
    print scalar @{ $_->{b} }, " bs\n";

    forcearray($_->{c});
    print scalar @{ $_->{c} }, " cs\n";
}
```

It fails on the last print with

> Not an ARRAY reference at ./tst_xml.pl line 16

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

```
sub forcearray {
  my $ref = shift;
  return [] if( !$ref );
  return $ref if( ref( $ref ) eq 'ARRAY' );
  return [ $ref ];
}
```

---

The [`XML::Bare::forcearray`](https://metacpan.org/source/CODECHILD/XML-Bare-0.53/Bare.pm#L469) function always returns an array reference, but it does not modify its input. So you need to use the return value of `forcearray`.

```
$_->{b} = forcearray($_->{b});
$_->{c} = forcearray($_->{c});
```